# Retrieve Tenured Generation memory pool from JVM

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, memory-pool

I am looking for a way to find the Tunered Generation pool inside the JVM, previously i tried to find this pool by name: "Tunered Gen" but  in some cases this pool named as "PS Old Gen". 
So i thought about more generic way to find the pool where all old objects are stored.

What do you think? maybe someone can suggest another solution?

```
    public MemoryPoolMXBean findTuneredGenerationMemoryPool(){

        List<MemoryPoolMXBean> memoryPoolsList = new ArrayList<MemoryPoolMXBean>();
        for(MemoryPoolMXBean pool: ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans()){
            if (pool.isCollectionUsageThresholdSupported() && pool.getType().equals( MemoryType.HEAP )){
                memoryPoolsList.add( pool );
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(memoryPoolsList, new Comparator<MemoryPoolMXBean>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(MemoryPoolMXBean pool, MemoryPoolMXBean otherPool) {

                return otherPool.getType().compareTo( pool.getType() );
            }});

        int oldestGenPoolIndex = memoryPoolsList.size() - 1;
        return memoryPoolsList.get( oldestGenPoolIndex );
    }
```

Regards,
Maxim

Comment: Questions asking for review of working code belong on Code Review (though Code Review may not have been around when you asked this question).  But here's one tip: sorting on the pool type makes no sense given you've already enforced that the pool type is equal to MemoryType.HEAP.